# Where to put Open Graph tags in Nextjs

Tags: next.js, metadata

We have a Next project where we want to put og tags to make sure our links show an image and a title. Since we have articles we would like to have a specific title and an image for every single link. So we cannot add static data and need to fetch dynamic data for each page. However, nothing works for us. We would like to know where to put meta tags to get the data correctly.

The only case is adding static data in _document.js that works.
[here is the proof that tags are added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jBy8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned `_document.js` I'll assume you're using [Pages Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages) over the newer [App Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application).

In your case, you should use the [`<Head>`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/head) component to include tags inside the page header. You can place this component anywhere in your component tree and Next.js will know where to put them in the final HTML.

For instance, in your page component you could:

```js
<Head>
  <meta property="og:title" content="My Cool Page" key="title" />
</Head>
// Rest of page component...
```

Notice that the `og:title` meta tag has a key that says `title`, this is not necessary but it can help with avoiding [duplicated tags](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/head#avoid-duplicated-tags) which can happen if the component tree includes multiple of the same tag.

Comment: however, your answer didn't help

Comment: Are you really using the pages router or the app router?

Comment: Im using Pages Router

Comment: This should work then, how are you testing whether the og tags are working or not? Are you checking that the tags are present in the page header with the dev tools?

Comment: yep, I checked the tags with the dev tools, and the tags are shown correctly. I'm using Facebook Share debugger, which doesn't show the meta tags.

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to run the Facebook Debugger with `localhost` as the URL? In that case, it obviously won't be displayed, the testing URL needs to be publicly accessible because the crawler that reads your meta tags is not in your browser.

Comment: Nope. I'm crawling the public website URL.

Comment: Hi there! So after struggling a lot, we found the issue. We had turned off ssr in our _app.tsx causing this file to render on the client side. This was the main issue; after fixing it, meta tags worked as expected. Also,  would like to mention that instead of looking at the devtools 'Elements' section, we had to look for the meta tags in Page source or devtools 'Sources' section. And initially, there was nothing from my meta tags. Anyway, thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

So after struggling a lot, we found the issue. We had turned off ssr in our _app.tsx causing this file to render on the client side. This was the main issue; after fixing it, meta tags worked as expected. Also, would like to mention that instead of looking at the devtools 'Elements' section, we had to look for the meta tags in Page source or devtools 'Sources' section. And initially, there was nothing from my meta tags. Anyway, thank you for your answers!